# Messed-up anime about a girl who gets brutally dismembered after a man paints a picture of her

Tags: story-identification, anime

**Can someone identify this anime for me?**

I only saw one clip, but in it a man is painting a woman and she makes some comment about people always wanting to kill and tear her apart. The man finishes his painting and reveals it to her, only to show that he had painted her in a demonic spooky manner. She gets very angry and he seemingly murders her and chops her up. The pieces that have been chopped up begin to regenerate into separate people presumably copies of her.

This is all I can recall, any help would be great.

Comment: Please refrain from rude language on this site. You may also want to check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like [Painter](http://junjiitomanga.wikia.com/wiki/Painter), one of Junji Ito's Tomie stories:

> While sitting for her portrait, Tomie tells Mori that every man who has ever loved her has tried to kill her, and she doesn't know why. Mori paints a picture of her with a hideous, monstrous face coming from her own beautiful one; just like the photos his friend took. Tomie hates the painting and sneers at it, causing Mori to fly into a homicidal rage and chop her into pieces.
>
> After a few days, the severed body parts begin to slowly regenerate. Mori knows that they will all become new copies of Tomie, but doesn't expect to live to see this happen, because he can't eat and is wasting away.

The version I'm familiar with is from the manga, but it looks like an [anime version was made too](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMg67YopM30).

Comment: What a weird thing I just watched.